# Isolate alphabetical strings within a larger string

Tags: r, string, sorting, alphabetical

Is there a way to isolate parts of a string that are in alphabetical order?

In other words, if you have a string like this: `hjubcdepyvb`

Could you just pull out the portion in alphabetical order?: `bcde`

I have thought about using the `is.unsorted()` function, but I'm not sure how to apply this to only a portion of a string.

Answer (score 8):

Here's one way by converting to ASCII and back:

```
input <- "hjubcdepyvb"
spl_asc <- as.integer(charToRaw(input))       # Convert to ASCII
d1 <- diff(spl_asc) == 1                      # Find sequences
filt <- spl_asc[c(FALSE, d1) | c(d1, FALSE)]  # Only keep sequences (incl start and end)
rawToChar(as.raw(filt))                       # Convert back to character

#[1] "bcde"
```

Note that this will concatenate any parts that are in alphabetical order.

i.e. If input is `"abcxasdicfgaqwe"` then output would be `abcfg`.

If you wanted to get separate vectors for each sequential string, you could do the following

```
input <- "abcxasdicfgaqwe"
spl_asc <- as.integer(charToRaw(input))
d1 <- diff(spl_asc) == 1
r <- rle(c(FALSE, d1) | c(d1, FALSE))                   # Find boundaries
cm <- cumsum(c(1, r$lengths))                           # Map these to string positions
substring(input, cm[-length(cm)], cm[-1] - 1)[r$values] # Extract matching strings
```

Finally, I had to come up with a way to use regex:

```
input <- c("abcxasdicfgaqwe", "xufasiuxaboqdasdij", "abcikmcapnoploDEFgnm",
           "acfhgik")
(rg <- paste0("(", paste0(c(letters[-26], LETTERS[-26]),
                           "(?=", c(letters[-1], LETTERS[-1]), ")", collapse = "|"), ")+."))

#[1] "(a(?=b)|b(?=c)|c(?=d)|d(?=e)|e(?=f)|f(?=g)|g(?=h)|h(?=i)|i(?=j)|j(?=k)|
#k(?=l)|l(?=m)|m(?=n)|n(?=o)|o(?=p)|p(?=q)|q(?=r)|r(?=s)|s(?=t)|t(?=u)|u(?=v)|
#v(?=w)|w(?=x)|x(?=y)|y(?=z)|A(?=B)|B(?=C)|C(?=D)|D(?=E)|E(?=F)|F(?=G)|G(?=H)|
#H(?=I)|I(?=J)|J(?=K)|K(?=L)|L(?=M)|M(?=N)|N(?=O)|O(?=P)|P(?=Q)|Q(?=R)|R(?=S)|
#S(?=T)|T(?=U)|U(?=V)|V(?=W)|W(?=X)|X(?=Y)|Y(?=Z))+."

regmatches(input, gregexpr(rg, input, perl = TRUE))
#[[1]]
#[1] "abc" "fg" 
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "ab" "ij"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "abc" "nop" "DEF"
#
#[[4]]
#character(0)
```

This regular expression will identify consecutive upper or lower case letters (but not mixed case). As demonstrated, it works for character vectors and produces a list of vectors with all the matches identified. If no match is found, the output is `character(0)`.

Answer (score 4):

Using factor integer conversion:

```
input <- "hjubcdepyvb"
d1 <- diff(as.integer(factor(unlist(strsplit(input, "")), levels = letters))) == 1
filt <- c(FALSE, d1) | c(d1, FALSE)
paste(unlist(strsplit(input, ""))[filt], collapse = "")
# [1] "bcde"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
myf = function(x){
    x = unlist(strsplit(x, ""))
    ind = charmatch(x, letters)
    d = c(0, diff(ind))
    d[d !=1] = 0
    d = d + c(sapply(1:(length(d)-1), function(i) {
        ifelse(d[i] == 0 & d[i+1] == 1, 1, 0)
    }
    ), 0)
    d = split(seq_along(d)[d!=0], with(rle(d), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))[d!=0])
    return(sapply(d, function(a) paste(x[a], collapse = "")))
}

myf(x = "hjubcdepyvblltpqrs")
#     2      4 
#"bcde" "pqrs"
```